# Display error in IE 9

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a coming soon page located at www.remindeals.com.

When the "get in first" button is clicked and an email submitted (do a fake one like abc@abc.com or whatever) there is a bug with the Modal popup where the background does not show and the social icons only appear when hovered over. This is a rails site built with bootstrap.

This problem only occurs in IE 9.. Anyone have any clues?

Attached below is the relevant jquery, not sure if this helps or not.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  // display validation errors for the "request invitation" form
  if ($('.alert-error').length > 0) {
    $("#request-invite").modal('toggle');
  }

  // use AJAX to submit the "request invitation" form
  $('#invitation_button').live('click', function() {
    var email = $('form #user_email').val();
    var password = $('form #user_password').val();
    var dataString = 'user[email]='+ email + '&user[password]=' + password;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/users",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#request-invite').html(data);
        loadSocial();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

})

// load social sharing scripts if the page includes a Twitter "share" button
function loadSocial() {

    //Twitter
    if (typeof (twttr) != 'undefined') {
      twttr.widgets.load();
    } else {
      $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
    }

    //Facebook
    if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined') {
      FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    } else {
      $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", function () {
        FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
      });
    }

    //Google+
    if (typeof (gapi) != 'undefined') {
      $(".g-plusone").each(function () {
        gapi.plusone.render($(this).get(0));
      });
    } else {
      $.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js');
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not saying what problem you're actually having?

Comment: IE9 has developer tools, try single stepping through your code.

Comment: @Pekka added what is going wrong

Comment: @greg i am not familiar with IE9 tools unfortunately.

Comment: @NKeating just hit F12 and go to console.  It'll show you where the errors are

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function() { <-- Document isn't supposed to be in quotes
```

Correct way is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { //code here });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page submits to the `thankyou.html` instead of opening the modal with social statistics when pressing `Enter` in the input field in IE. That's because the `#invitation_button`'s `click` event isn't fired when submitting by pressing `Enter` in the input field.

Wrap your text `input` and `submit` button in a `<form/>`, then replace:

```
$('#invitation_button').live('click', function() {
```

With:

```
$('form').live('submit', function() {
```

Or, as you're using jQuery 1.7.2:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
```

You may also consider using a CDN hosted jQuery copy instead of hosting it on your site as it provides better caching and load time for your users.

The rest of your page seems to behave the same as FF/Chrome in my IE.

Comment: thanks @fabricio .. I believe your fix worked on IE but a side effect seems to be when an error in the email input is rendered (just put in the letter "a" in email to trigger) the formatting is broken... Any ideas?